# Firefox refuses to start after being "killed" by PID

Tags: java, firefox, taskkill

I've programmatically killed Firefox Browser using the PID via taskkill:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /T /PID " + pid);
```

Now when I try opening Firefox again, I'm being show the message:

> Firefox closed unexpectedly while starting. This might be caused by add-ons or other problems..

With option to either `Refresh` or `Run in Safe Mode`.

Is there a way to kill/close Firefox browser without running into the above issue each time? I need to be able to close/kill Firefox programmatically [Java] using the PID.

Thanks

For those who requested, I'm running FF on Windows 10, FF version 77.0.1 64 Bit.